# How do I set a spawn point in a pvp scenario

Tags: factorio

I'm trying to make a PvP scenario where everybody starts in the middle of the map. at X,Y -12,16.

I don't want to use the Default PvP Scenario starts each team with a rocket silo. Also while I could use SpaceBook i don't want to because it leaves someone in power as an admin and I don't want that.

So is there a way i can set the spawn point without anyone being an admin or having a rocket silo? like through a mod or some other scenario customization?

Answer (score 2):

Short of finding an existing PvP Scenario that suits your needs, you can start a new game and manually configure teams and their spawn points. I found, but have not personally tested [this mod](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/TvT-scenarios) that appears to have spawn point settings and looks like an otherwise normal game.

## DIY Approach

Create a game with your desired settings. Make sure that you set yourself as an admin (for now) and start the game.

#### Create the teams

First, you'll need to create the teams. Open the console with <kbd>~</kbd> and enter the following (**N.B.** all commands can be pasted in game):

```
/c game.create_force('name')
```

Replace `name` with the desired force name, such as `'Team Awesome'` for example (the quotes are necessary). Repeat this process as needed for each desired force; you can press <kbd>↑</kbd> while in the console to reuse the last command.

**Note**: A "force" is the game's term for a team or faction.

#### Set spawn positions

Now that you have the forces created, you'll need to set their spawn points. To do so, use the following command:

```
/c game.forces['name'].set_spawn_position({x = #, y = #}, game.surfaces[1])

-- OR, to automatically use your current position
/c game.forces['name'].set_spawn_position(game.player.position, game.surfaces[1])
```

Replace the `#`s with the desired X and Y coordinates. A simple way to determine the coordinates of a specific spot is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd> somewhere on the map to create a map ping; the coordinates will then be displayed in the console.

#### Assign players to teams

To assign a player to a force, use the following command:

```
/c game.players['player_name'].force = game.forces['force_name']
```

To get a list of the current players:

```
/c for _, player in pairs(game.players) do game.print(player.name) end
```

Use one of these names in place of `'player_name'` above.

To get a list of the current forces:

```
/c for name, _ in pairs(game.forces) do game.print(name) end
```

You should see the three default forces: *player*, *enemy*, and *neutral*, along with the forces you added earlier. Use one of these names in place of `'force_name'`.

That's it! If you want, save and create a backup of the map, in case you need to start over, but don't want to set up the forces again.

## References

- https://wiki.factorio.com/Multiplayer#Forces
- https://lua-api.factorio.com
- [`LuaGameScript.create_force`](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/LuaGameScript.html#LuaGameScript.create_force)
- [`LuaForce.set_spawn_position`](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/LuaForce.html#LuaForce.set_spawn_position)
- [`LuaControl.position`](https://lua-api.factorio.com/latest/LuaControl.html#LuaControl.position)